# Does the property hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans works when getting a lazy field of an instance fetched from the audit table?

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-envers

We are using hibernate-envers to log the events, and we are using the api AuditReader for searching instances from the audit tables. To get a lazy field when the session is not opened, we used to add the property hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans and set it to true (it is a bad practice but we need it). But when we tried to get a lazy field of instances fetched from the audit tables, we got the LazyInitializationException .

Comment: Its possible that configuration property isn't being honored in the Envers use case; open a jira and attach a runnable test case based on our test cases from https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-test-case-templates/tree/master/envers/envers-5.

Comment: not working . tried it .